# DateTimeFormatter giving wrong format for edge cases

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

`DateTimeFormatter` is not giving correct format for Dec 30 and 31 2018 as per following snippet.

```
final String DATE_FORMAT = "YYYYMM";
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018,12,29,5,0,0);
System.out.println(startDate.format(dateFormat));
//prints 201812
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018,12,30,5,0,0);
System.out.println(startDate.format(dateFormat));
//prints 201912 <------ should be 201812
LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018,12,31,5,0,0);
System.out.println(startDate.format(dateFormat));
//prints 201912 <------ should be 201812
```

Is this the expected behavior or is there a bug with DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: did you recompile after you changed the code?

Comment: YYYYis week year, yyyy is year

Comment: Please read [SimpleTimeFormatter javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) carefully. Note that this is for Java 10.

Comment: you need to understand mechanism of YYYY & yyyy. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar

Comment: And to make this even more confusing, there are other formatters that use different patterns, most notably [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html)

Comment: @HULK I agree it may differ to language to language but there are some standard set in every language to avoid  any conflict.  Please read this URL-https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: @Kandy that's why I linked to the hugely popular JodaTime library which "is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8", and which handles `Y` as `year of era (>=0)` - don't assume anything about which parser/formatter implements which (parts of the) standard unless it explicitly documents compliance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YYYY is week year, yyyy is year

So Change `final String DATE_FORMAT = "YYYYMM";` ro  `final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMM";` should give you the correct result. For more informations about the patterns see the [javadoc of DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

The first week of 2019 starts at Dec 30 of 2018. See this [link](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019) for more informations about the week years

Comment: @OleV.V. The documentation of DateFormatter was not wo good until Java Version 7 so i liked to use the SimpleDateFormat documentation. I have seen it was changed in Version Java 8+ Thnks for the hint

Answer (score 10):

This is expected behaviour. `YYYY` stands for "week-based-year", which is not the same as calendar year (see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html))

You most probably want to use `yyyy`, which means "year-of-era"

Answer (score 2):

`y` is for "year-of-era" while `Y` is for `week-based-year`

Replace:

```
final String DATE_FORMAT = "YYYYMM";
```

to:

```
final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMM";
```